# Failed at linking C++ [undefined reference boost::filesystem3 ... ]

Tags: c++, boost, reference, undefined

I'm having some trouble compiling my work, I'm using Ubuntu with `g++`. I get a lot of these messages:

```
undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::directory_entry::m_get_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::extension() const'
undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::filename() const'
undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::filename() const'
```

(etc...)

I've searched and found many answers but none of those work for me.

```
-lboost_system (/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libboost_system.so)
-lboost_filesystem (/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libboost_filesystem.so)
```

When linking it shows those two libraries, I'm guessing the error is related to the second one.

```
hax@lap:~$ locate libboost_filesystem.so
/home/hax/boost_1_47_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.4.5/release/threading-multi/libboost_filesystem.so.1.47.0
/home/hax/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
/home/hax/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.47.0
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0
/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.47.0
```

This is the related line on my makefile:

```
-L. -L../bncsutil/src/bncsutil/ -L../StormLib/stormlib/ -L../boost/lib/ -lbncsutil -lpthread -ldl -lz -lStorm -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem  -Wl -t
```

I tried pointing with -L several different places where I saw filesystem.so was located but it didn't work!

Can anyone see the problem in those lines? If you need me to put some extra data I'll do it, I'm not seeing the problem :(

Comment: What is relative position of -lxxxxx options to your .o file in the combined command line? One of compilers I work with requires that the prerequisites should be to the right of the objects (libs). Something like : g++ -o a.out main.o -lbuzz -lbar -lfoo. Some other compilers require the reverse order of libs/object files. Try changing the order and see what happens.

Comment: g++ -o [OUTPUT] [ALL .O HERE] -L. -L../bncsutil/src/bncsutil/ -L../StormLib/stormlib/ -L../boost/lib/ -lbncsutil -lpthread -ldl -lz -lStorm -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem  -Wl -t -lrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost looks like it's trying to link to the 1.42.0 version which may not contain those symbols. You could remove the 1.42.0 version, run ldconfig, and try your luck again.

Comment: Just deleting the .so of the 1.42? or do i have to delete extra files? anyway, i think this is kinda relevant--->

Just noticed this line on the big compiling log:

"/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.42.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libboost_filesystem.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)"

libboost_system.so.1.42.0 is located just on /usr/lib, not on /usr/bin/ld (in fact ld inside bin is not a folder, it is some kind of binary).

Any ideas about that? should i create a folder ld and copy that file inside it? it doesn't sound right

Comment: Remove the Boost libraries from your distribution install or upgrade them. Why are you compiling Boost by hand anyways?

Comment: I don't remember how did i install Boost, i guess i installed it through apt-get.

Is there a easy way to delete alllll of its files? i will do an apt-get remove libboost*. But since i apparently have two versions...

Comment: ooooooookay i did an apt-get remove libboost* and just in case tried to compile and it did work with no errors!
what happened?!

Comment: The compile job was attempting to link to the 1.42.0 version installed on your system. Removing the 1.42.0 system install fixes the problem because they're not there anymore to link to. Don't forget to mark as answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nick Betcher is right. You are mixing two versions of boost::filesystem binaries. By default, boost 1.42 is building with version 2 and Boost 1.47 with version 3.

Alternatively you can define a macro BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2; it disables features of version 3 and the linker errors dismiss.