# Boost filesystem3 calls undefined

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, linker-errors, boost-filesystem

Encountering "boost::filesystem3" undefined reference errors while trying to link:

```
RawStreamReader.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost11filesystem34path4leafEv[_ZNK5boost11filesystem34path4leafEv]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::filename() const'
```

This is on Linux 64.
I rebuilt the boost 1.55 with same c++11 options that I am using for my build.

The output from this symbol dump seems to indicate that none of the symbols contain "filesystem3" in the name (the 3 part is missing).

Note, that I have read these questions / answers (to no avail):

- [Failed at linking C++ [undefined reference boost::filesystem3 ... ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264055/failed-at-linking-c-undefined-reference-boostfilesystem3)
- [c++ boost::filesystem undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::root_name() const'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972314/c-boostfilesystem-undefined-reference-to-boostfilesystem3pathroot-nam)

The code is compiling on other systems against same boost version. This is a fresh install with a new cmake build setup that I am trying to debug. All other boost libraries seem to be linking fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally *link* with an incorrect Boost version (not 1.55 as you suppose, but some older version, eg. available at `/usr/lib/`)?

Comment: I have removed the other boost libraries and have cmake FIND_BOOST in verbose mode reporting the include version and lib version. Both are 1.55